# Why is A* used as global planner in move_base?

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can someone shed some light on why A* star is used for global planner in move_base. I can see that there is an option to use Djikstra's algorithm as well. What are the main benefits of A* as opposed to using RRT or RRT*?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332815/why-is-a*-used-as-global-planner-in-move_base-?/) by [robot_new_user](https://answers.ros.org/users/44888/robot_new_user/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LeoE](https://answers.ros.org/users/38438/leoe/) on 2019-09-11**:
There is a Stackoverflow post about A* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511118/is-a-the-best-pathfinding-algorithm) take a look at that, mybe this gives a bit of an insight, also [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3d7a/a9dd92c62c87c72514eeea3c38b090c51531.pdf) you can find a comparison between Dijkstra and RRT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Outside of RRT, [here are my thoughts on using A* vs Djikstras](https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation/tree/master/dlux_plugins)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2019-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a good basic reference for A* vs  Dijkstra. A* has an added heuristic trying to expand the potential field in the direction of the goal. Its not necessarily promised to be faster, but in most cases it is.

[http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/AStarComparison.html](http://theory.stanford.edu/%7Eamitp/GameProgramming/AStarComparison.html)

RRT and RRT-variants are sampling based and not search based. They will require smoothing after the search. In practice RRTs are nice for higher dimensional spaces like manipulators, but in lower dimensional space (like 2D mobile robots) its not really adventitious over search based. WIth that said, there are RRT implemented global planner plugins if you google for it for you to try out youself if you like.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-09-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5